# C# scrolling of richtextbox

Tags: c#, text, methods, richtextbox, scroll

Is there a method to scroll the richtextbox to the top automatically with codes?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by *with codes*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you mean bottom?

instance.SelectionStart = instance.Text.Length;

or i guess top would be instance.SelectionStart = 0.

Answer (score 6):

Set [`.SelectionStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart.aspx)`=0` and then [`.ScrollToCaret()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
richTextBox.SelectionStart = richTextBox.Text.Length;
richTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

tRY the above  2 lines of code  it worked for me!