# Auto adjust scrollbar without mouse drag

Tags: c#, scrollbar

In my project i have the tabControl shown below and inside of it i have a richTextBox on which i enabled the Vertical ScrollBar...
In the richTextBox i have some "Assembly commands" and each time i highlight the instruction that is executed. My problem is when some of the last instructions i have in the textbox, must execute, those are not visible, so i have to drag manually the scrollbar.

What i'm trying to do is to set the scrollbar to move up/down by itself without any user interaction.

is there any possible solution for my problem? thanks

[image]

Comment: [Relevant link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373433/c-sharp-scrolling-of-richtextbox) <- possibly answer

Comment: the link just tells you how to set scrollbar show at the end of the richtextbox.. What i want is to automatically adjust the scroll bar

Comment: It looks like you are going to have to extract pieces from other posts/code and then formulate your own code- then if you are unable to get that working, post the code and how to get it to work- part of development is working through critical thinking. There are a bunch of nested links here at SO (I know can be a pain to find)- here are some...[one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11966037/how-to-set-scroll-position-of-rich-text-box-control) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827323/c-synchronize-scroll-position-of-two-richtextboxes) (hold on there are more)

Comment: [three](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) [four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490182/how-to-get-scroll-position-for-richtextbox) [five](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7830/Scrolling-Around-with-the-RichTextBox-Control)- You'll have to do some creative development it seems from reading through some of these posts.